# selecting time in between a range for different and same dates

Tags: mysql, date, datetime, time, range

Hi I have a table which stores date and time seperately. the two columns are say Ddate (date type) and Dtime( time type). It also has other columns say SenderName,Sendercounty,Senderdetails. I  need to select these details for a date range between a date time.
e.g. if the Ddate selected is 01/02/2019 to 03/02/2019 and Dtime from 17:00:00 to 05:00:00 . How do I make sure the start time maps to start date and end time maps to end date and returns all records in between in my query. I had this query which worked fine as we always selected only one date before but now we need a date range and this fails.

```
select Sender.SenderName,           
count(product.id) as totalProduct,                      
Sender.Dtime as Ttime,                      
Sender.Ddate                        
from Sender                  
inner join  product                 
on Sender.productId = product.id
where (product.Type in ('s','w','q') and    product.status='a')                                     
                    and Sender.Ddate between '2019-02-01'  and  '2019-02-04'
                    and Sender.Dtime between  '17:00:00' and '05:00:00'                     
                    group by product.id order by Sender.Dtime asc
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show a few rows of your table and your desired results.

Answer (score 0):

`and Sender.Dtime between  '17:00:00' and '05:00:00'` cannot possibly return any rows, because 5--the end of your range--is less than 17. `between` is not smart enough to know you're working with wrapping-around times.

It looks like you need anything between 1700 on one day and 0500 on the next day. To do this you can try

```
 and ( Sender.Dtime >= '17:00:00' OR Sender.Dtime <= '05:00:00' )
```

Comment: Thanks, ye agree 'between' is not smart enough. If I use above it still returns nothing.  for e.g. user tried between 6 am today and 5:59 am next day and it returns nothing when we know there are 33 records

Comment: Also how will it work for a date range with 2 or multiple days in between